# error FS0193: internal error: Could not load type

Tags: f#

I found several, usually 2 years and older stack overflow questions regarding this error. But after inspecting the samples those other questions gave, this question is not a duplicate. The other questions were mostly about structs with layout attributes. In my case, there is nothing fancy about the code whatsoever - except that it also produces this error:

```
[<Struct>]
type Vertex =
    val x : float
    val y : float
    val z : float
    new(_x:float,_y:float,_z:float) = { x = _x; y = _y; z = _z}

[<Struct>]
type Triangle =
    val v0 : Vertex
    val v1 : Vertex
    val v2 : Vertex
    new(_v0:Vertex,_v1:Vertex,_v2:Vertex) = { v0 = _v0; v1 = _v1; v2 = _v2 }

let v0 = Vertex(0.0,0.0,0.0)
let v1 = Vertex(0.0,1.0,0.0)
let v2 = Vertex(1.0,1.0,0.0)

let t0 = Triangle(v0,v1,v2)
```

The last line (instantiating a triangle) produces in fsi the error:

> error FS0193: internal error: Could not load type 'Triangle' from assembly  'FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Please note, that the `Vertex` (which has float members) works as expected.
The Triangle which has `Vertex` members does not.

Following up the respective github f# bugs, I got the impression there has been a fix long ago. But I get this in:

> Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 14.0.23413.0

I did not try if it works inside a compiled assembly (F# project), but my guess is, it would work.

Now the question is: Did I just make some stupid oversight error or is this a bug or are struct members inside struct forbidden?

Comment: Funny, just an hour ago I [reported a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1713) with the same error message

Comment: @Gustavo Maybe it is a regression bug o.O In older github entries, DSyme himself stated there had been a fix...

Comment: Do you know where he stated that? Link?

Comment: @Gustavo https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/342

Comment: I can reproduce this, but only in interactive. I use nested structs with explicit layout for OpenGL interop and don't recall ever running into this error. But when I just pasted my code into FSI, I ran into the same issue. It looks like nested structs are broken in interactive.